# Google Visualization - joining multiple DataTables in Java

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

Basically I'm creating a GWT application using the google App Engine (Java), the Datastore and Google Visualization charts.

I used a simple line chart to represent the following information - Value(Y-axis) over Year(X-axis)

I'm getting the following values from the Datastore as a list of entities:

Request for Jon returns Entities (each row is an entity):

```
Person | Value | Year
Jon    |  80%  | 1992
Jon    |  74%  | 2010
Jon    |  10%  | 2011 
Jon    |  84%  | 2012
```

Request for Mike Returns:

```
Person | Value | Year
Mike   |  80%  | 2000
Mike   |  74%  | 2001
Mike   |  10%  | 2002 
Mike   |  84%  | 2003
Mike   |  85%  | 2006
Mike   |  65%  | 2011
Mike   |  55%  | 2012
```

I can create a graph for each person easily. I do so by creating the [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_javadocs/com/google/visualization/datasource/datatable/package-summary) on the Server using the following [Google Visualization Data Source Library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_javadocs/index?com/google/visualization/datasource/package-summary.html) - I then send it back using Json.

Now what I'd like is to create a graph which combines/joins both DataTables

The only other way I can see myself implementing this is by creating each [TableRow](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_javadocs/com/google/visualization/datasource/datatable/TableRow) individually - and this just feels like overkill for me at the moment because the data must be in the correct column for each person i.e. TableRow for year 2012 would need to be

```
Year |Mike | Jon
2006 | 85% | null
2011 | 65% | 10%
2010 | null| 84%
2011 | 65% | 10%
2012 | 55% | 84%
```

This is especially tricky for me because I send separate requests for each person - so for example if I request Jon then I get a list of entities representing each row , but when I want to JOIN them I need to go through the pain of getting the year, adding the value to the right column etc etc. This just all seems like overkill, there must be a way to merge tables so that you can generate the above set of rows automatically.

What I want is simply to generate a DataTable for Jon and Mike and Sally if she comes along, and then Merge them all in one simple command so that I get a nice chart with each line mapped to the correct person.

p.s I this code should be written in Java on the Server...

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it with google tables?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to solve this.. like `union` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to join two Datatables into one:

google.visualization.data.join(dt1, dt2, joinMethod, keys, dt1Columns, dt2Columns)

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_join

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice the setCell method of the DataTable - I was too busy at looking at the addRow addCell methods...

See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews

Still - would be great to able to merge two datatables......

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to JSON and merge them.
The sample below is written in Javascript, but the method is same in Java.

```
    var json1 = JSON.parse(dataTable1.toJSON());
    var json2 = JSON.parse(dataTable2.toJSON());
    var mergedRows = json1.rows.concat(json2.rows);

    json1.rows = mergedRows;
    var mergedDataTable= new google.visualization.DataTable(json1);
```

Comment: The problem with this is it doesn't preserve the unique column names from each data table, they all get merged into whatever column json1 has.  All the data shows up, but the legend will only have one label instead of one for each series.